# Chrome inserting hidden CSS styling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My website's footer has `div` elements inside of it. These `div`s are visible by any browser other than chrome. Initially, I put some SVGs in those `div` elements but deleted them. Upon inspecting the `div`s I see that there is some hidden styling added by chrome. I'm not sure if this is due to those SVGs from way back.

**The CSS is this:**

```
display: none !important;
```

I try to find what file this CSS is attributed to, and it says it's a style tag inside `index.html`. However, it's not visible in my `index.html`.

What's happening here and how do I remove this hidden inline styling messing up my website?

Comment: Disable your extensions.

Comment: Clean browser cache and reload page  Or I guess that is the cause of media queries , if u provide code sample it may easy to debug and help

Comment: provide more details and  sample working code / screenshot